# How to send a filled form back to client from Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js. I am trying to implement a simple "search" application. I have created a simple HTML page that has a search column at the top and result text field in the middle. The user will enter search text and submit the text to node.js. I know how to handle 'POST' in node.js. But, I do not know, how to fill the result field in the same HTML file and send back to the client. I searched in the internet, but I found that most of the examples talks about handling POST request and send a simple confirmation back to the client.

Comment: Do you mean server side rendered full page or ajax based request? The easier approach would be by using ajax without the full page refresh.

Comment: Thanks. I will try using AJAX.

Comment: If found a nice tutorial on this page, on using Ajax with Node.js https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-ajax/intro-ajax-the-nodejs-server.cfm